# JQuery Tablesorter not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am parsing an XML file into a table and want to use the jquery tablesorter. I've tried many things, of which none have worked.  I was parsing the XML file first via AJAX and then calling tablesorter on my table.  The way I have my code now, I'm calling tablesorter on my table, running AJAX, and then updating the table with `$("#table).trigger("update")`. I am getting this error no matter whether I have it the first way or the second way: "$(#table).tablesorter() is not a function". Any ideas? Code is listed below for JS and HTML.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Read XML</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item #</th>
                <th>Shape</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Clarity</th>
                <th>Price($)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#table").tablesorter();
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "tutorial.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: parseXml
 });
$("#table").trigger("update");
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
    $(xml).find("diamond").each(function()
    {
        $("#table tbody").after("<tr><td>" + $(this).find("id").text() + 
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("shape").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("weight").text() + 
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("color").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("clarity").text() + 
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("price").text() + "</td></tr>");
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: i saw it in an example, and it is also listed on the tablesorter webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing `>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"</script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

Edit:

As [Marek Karbarz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77017/marek-karbarz) points out below, you're also missing a closing `>` on this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"</script>
```

Not sure why you're including jQuery twice, however.

Comment: Same with the line above that for jquery.latest.js

Comment: thank you! now, I'm having a problem with it actually letting me sort.

Comment: @Brandon: Happy to help. It's probably best to start a new question for that (since it's a new issue). If this solved the original question, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Comment: will do...i've got 4 minutes til i can check it solved. but i will start a new question in a second. thank you.